# How can I make a dashboard that shows all active burndown charts in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I have several project in TFS 2013. I want a dashboard that shows the burndown charts for all projects, and shows a warning if there is not enough capacity available for the work remaining per project. How can I make such a dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. If you have SharePoint integration enabled, then it may be used for such purpose, but you'll need to create the burndown for each project using the Excel web parts manually.

A custom report on Report Server would also work.

Capacity is not available in the warehouse, so it's going to be based on remaining work and the burnrate, but it cannot see whether there are enough weekdays or whether team days off are making it impossible to reach the goal.